# The first buttons work, the second do not

Tags: javascript, html, button, onclick

The first section works. When i press +, it works. Nothing works after the +. I press the plus and the second set of buttons appear, but pressing them does nothing. By the way, I am making a calculator.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>
JavaScript
</title>
</head>
<body>
<script>
var first = ""
document.write('<button onclick="one()">1</button>');
document.write('<button onclick="two()">2</button><br/>');
document.write('<button onclick="three()">3</button>');
document.write('<button onclick="four()">4</button><br/>');
document.write('<button onclick="five()">5</button>');
document.write('<button onclick="six()">6</button><br/>');
document.write('<button onclick="seven()">7</button>');
document.write('<button onclick="eight()">8</button><br/>');
document.write('<button onclick="nine()">9</button>');
document.write('<button onclick="zero()">0</button><br/>');
document.write('<button onclick="add()">+</button><br/>');
function one(){
first = first + "1";
}
function two(){
first = first + "2";
}
function three(){
first = first + "3";
}
function four(){
first = first + "4";
}
function five(){
first = first + "5";
}
function six(){
first = first + "6";
}
function seven(){
first = first + "7";
}
function eight(){
first = first + "8";
}
function nine(){
first = first + "9";
}
function zero(){
first = first + "0";
}
function add(){
document.body.innerHTML = '';
var second = ""
document.write('<button onclick="one()">1</button>');
document.write('<button onclick="two()">2</button><br/>');
document.write('<button onclick="three()">3</button>');
document.write('<button onclick="four()">4</button><br/>');
document.write('<button onclick="five()">5</button>');
document.write('<button onclick="six()">6</button><br/>');
document.write('<button onclick="seven()">7</button>');
document.write('<button onclick="eight()">8</button><br/>');
document.write('<button onclick="nine()">9</button>');
document.write('<button onclick="zero()">0</button><br/>');
document.write('<button onclick="equal()">=</button><br/>');
function one(){
second = second + "1";
}
function two(){
second = second + "2";
}
function three(){
second = second + "3";
}
function four(){
second = second + "4";
}
function five(){
second = second + "5";
}
function six(){
second = second + "6";
}
function seven(){
second = second + "7";
}
function eight(){
second = second + "8";
}
function nine(){
second = second + "9";
}
function zero(){
second = second + "0";
}
function equal(){
first = Math.floor;
second = Math.floor;
answer = first + second;
document.write(answer);
}
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The 1990's called, they want their Javascript back. Don't use `document.write()`, learn how to use DOM modification functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you had with your original solution was that the functions in the second calculator were in the private scope of the add() function, but the HTML `<button>`s are in the global scope, so there was no way for them to access the functions to add numbers to your 'second' variable.

Here's your code, with both sets of function in the global scope

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>
JavaScript
</title>
</head>
<body>
<script>

first = ""
document.write('<button onclick="first_one()">1</button>');
document.write('<button onclick="first_two()">2</button>');
document.write('<button onclick="first_three()">3</button>');
document.write('<button onclick="first_four()">4</button>');
document.write('<button onclick="first_five()">5</button>');
document.write('<button onclick="first_six()">6</button>');
document.write('<button onclick="first_seven()">7</button>');
document.write('<button onclick="first_eight()">8</button>');
document.write('<button onclick="first_nine()">9</button>');
document.write('<button onclick="first_zero()">0</button>');
document.write('<button onclick="first_add()">+</button>');

function first_one(){
first = first + "1";
}
function first_two(){
first = first + "2";
}
function first_three(){
first = first + "3";
}
function first_four(){
first = first + "4";
}
function first_five(){
first = first + "5";
}
function first_six(){
first = first + "6";
}
function first_seven(){
first = first + "7";
}
function first_eight(){
first = first + "8";
}
function first_nine(){
first = first + "9";
}
function first_zero(){
first = first + "0";
}

function first_add() {

second = ""

document.write('<button onclick="second_one()">1</button>');
document.write('<button onclick="second_two()">2</button><br/>');
document.write('<button onclick="second_three()">3</button>');
document.write('<button onclick="second_four()">4</button><br/>');
document.write('<button onclick="second_five()">5</button>');
document.write('<button onclick="second_six()">6</button><br/>');
document.write('<button onclick="second_seven()">7</button>');
document.write('<button onclick="second_eight()">8</button><br/>');
document.write('<button onclick="second_nine()">9</button>');
document.write('<button onclick="second_zero()">0</button><br/>');
document.write('<button onclick="second_equal()">=</button><br/>');

}

function second_one(){
second = second + "1";
}
function second_two(){
second = second + "2";
}
function second_three(){
second = second + "3";
}
function second_four(){
second = second + "4";
}
function second_five(){
second = second + "5";
}
function second_six(){
second = second + "6";
}
function second_seven(){
second = second + "7";
}
function second_eight(){
second = second + "8";
}
function second_nine(){
second = second + "9";
}
function second_zero(){
second = second + "0";
}

function second_equal(){
document.write((parseInt(first) + parseInt(second)).toString());
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This works great, i was declaring functions inside functions. It makes sense now.

Answer (score 0):

Hey see if this work.

```
<script>
var data ="";
var first = "";
var sum = "";
document.write('<button onclick="one()">1</button>');
document.write('<button onclick="two()">2</button><br/>');
document.write('<button onclick="three()">3</button>');
document.write('<button onclick="four()">4</button><br/>');
document.write('<button onclick="five()">5</button>');
document.write('<button onclick="six()">6</button><br/>');
document.write('<button onclick="seven()">7</button>');
document.write('<button onclick="eight()">8</button><br/>');
document.write('<button onclick="nine()">9</button>');
document.write('<button onclick="zero()">0</button><br/>');
document.write('<button onclick="add()">+</button>');
document.write('<button onclick="equal()">=</button><br/>');
document.write('<div id =\"sum\"> </div><br/>');
function one(){
data = data + "1";
}
function two(){
data = data + "2";
}
function three(){
data = data + "3";
}
function four(){
data = data + "4";
}
function five(){
data = data + "5";
}
function six(){
data = data + "6";
}
function seven(){
data = data + "7";
}
function eight(){
data = data + "8";
}
function nine(){
data = data + "9";
}
function zero(){
data = data + "0";
}
function add(){
 first = data;
 data= "";
}

function equal(){
 sum = parseInt(first) + parseInt(data);



 //document.getElementById("sum").remove();
 document.getElementById("sum").innerHTML =   sum  ;

      data ="";
  first = "";
 sum = "";
}




</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues on your code example.

- Methods that are wired on markup needs to be defined on window and hence when you click on any number after clicking on + , all the methods point to the functions that are defined outside the add function
- Also, the way you redefined methods inside add() those methods are only available inside the function scope of add and they dont override the methods that are defined globally, but when you access them inside the add method (not in document.write), they will point to the methods inside add function.
- Math.floor is a method and need the argument.[Math.Floor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor)